# How to add mutiple attachments to an Email python

Tags: python

I need to add multiple attachments to send an Email automatically through python script..

Im new to python scripting. so pls help. Thanks in advance..

Below is the code snippet.

Please let me know what change i have to do to the below code.

```
themsg = MIMEMultipart()
themsg['Subject'] = Subject
themsg['To'] =','.join(Email_ID)
themsg['From'] =email_from
themsg.preamble = 'I am not using a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
msg = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
msg.set_payload(zf_csv.read())
zf_csv.close()
msg.set_payload(zf_pdf.read())
zf_pdf.close()
Encoders.encode_base64(msg)
print 'csv attachment is'+str(os.path.basename(current_dirs+csv_to_mail))
print 'pdf attachment is'+str(os.path.basename(current_dirs+pdf_to_mail))
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="(%s,%s)"' %(os.path.basename(current_dirs+csv_to_mail),os.path.basename(current_dirs+pdf_to_mail))
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Hi jamylak, i need to write a python script that adds multiple attachements(more than one attachment) to an email and send it automatically to some emai ids. I have added the  code snippet to my question

Comment: @user1240863 Ok now this question is all right.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to_addrs_list) 
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
msg['Cc'] = COMMASPACE.join(cc_addrs_list)
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msgAlternative)
msgAlternative.attach(MIMEText(content, 'plain'))

#add mutiple attachments to an Email
#attachment_paths is a list, like this:['/home/x/a.pdf', '/home/x/b.txt']
for file_path in attachment_paths:
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
    if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
        ctype = dctype
    maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            part = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
            part.set_payload(f.read())
            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(file_path))
            print os.path.basename(file_path)
            msg.attach(part)
    except IOError:
         print "error: Can't open the file %s"%file_path
```

There is the **[full code](https://gist.github.com/2780008)**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know any better way to send mails using python, than using lamsonproject (lamsonproject.org).

Their API also includes adding attachments to mails - and nothing stops you from adding multiple attachments to mail. Just look up API about MailResponse and its attach method.